# user.findOne() is not a funtion

Tags: mysql, node.js

please my code is returning an error that
user.findOne is not a function

```
user.js

module.exports = class User {
     constructor(name, email, password, phoneNumber) {
            this.name = name;
            this.email = email;
            this.password = password;
            this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;           
        }
    save() {
        return dbs.execute(
            'INSERT INTO user (name, email, password, phoneNumber ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)',
            [this.name, this.email, this.password, this.phoneNumber]
            );
    };

    static findById(){
        return dbs.execute('SELECT * FROM user WHERE user.email = ?', [email]);

    }

    static fetchAll(){
        return dbs.execute('SELECT * FROM user');
    };
};
```

this is the login.js code

```
login.js

const User = require('../model/user');

exports.getLogin = (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('login/login');
};

exports.postLogin = (req, res, next) => {
    const email = req.body.email; 
    const password = req.body.password;    
    User.findOne({email: email})    
     .then(user => {
         if(!user){
             req.flash('error', 'user does not exist');
             return res.redirect('/sign-up');
         }
        }) 
     .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

when i run the code it returns an error message that the findOne() is not a function
what can i do to resolve this error

Comment: Where do you have the findOne method mentioned in user.js file?

Comment: do i have to mention it in user.js file before i can use it anywhere?

Comment: Yes, you have to define it before using.

Comment: i defined the findOne, but the browser keeps loading non-stop

any idea